# Question about unbiased estimate for $P(X<a)$

Tags: probability, self-study, estimation

Let $X$ be $Normal(\mu,\sigma^2)$, $\sigma$ is known. I need to find an unbiased estimate for $P(X<0)$. My question is, is it enough to find an unbiased estimate for $\mu$ and use that? That is, is $P(X<0|\bar x)$ unbiased for $P(X<0|\mu)$? I'm thinking it is not. If it is not, how do I find an unbiased estimate then?

Comment: @Tim $\mu$ is unknown. I have a sample instead so I can use the sample mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your thinking is right, that obtaining an unbiased estimator for $\mu$ is not sufficient, this $\mu \to P(X<0)$ may not be a linear function.

Note that $P(X < 0) = E \left[I(X <0) \right]$, where $I()$ is the indicator function. This representation makes it easier to find an unbiased estimator because for $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} f(X_i)$ is an unbiased estimator of $E[f(x)]$.
So, an unbiased estimator of $P(X < 0)$ is $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}I(X_i < 0)$ which counts the proportion of observations below 0.

In practice with only one sample, $I(X <0 )$ will either be 1 or 0, and thus will be not a good estimator, although it is still of course unbiased. With only one sample, other estimators will also not be good estimators. JarleTufto's estimator is not valid with one sample since $a$ is not defined.

Comment: This works even for a single sample, correct? All I need is an unbiased estimator which I then intend to condition to find a UMVUE. I'm thinking about how to use that indicator function but it's not coming to me. I tried taking iterated expectation but it seemed like a dead end

Comment: @user164144 why do you need to need to condition? Is the indicator, or linear combinations of the indicator an unbiased estimator?

Comment: @user164144 It *works* for one sample in the sense that the estimator is unbiased, how ever it will be an awful estimator in practice. Why do you need an iterated expectation? I would suggest you edit the question showing your steps, and discuss where you're getting stuck, because the answer is fairly starightforward.

Comment: Yes. I need it because in the actual problem, I do not have a sample of X's but rather a sample of Y's and Z's of different sizes, where the parameter of X is a linear function of the parameters of Y and Z. So what I was planning was to get an unbiased estimator based on X and then condition it on complete sufficient stats for parameters of Y and Z.

Comment: @user164144 My answer answers the question you asked. It seems like you need an answer to a completely different question, so I would suggest you ask that question directly. Edit the question or ask a new question!

Comment: Apologies for the confusion. I didn't spell out the original question since like you said, this is a self-study item. I only wanted to gain insight on the part of the problem I was confused with. Which is basically finding an unbiased estimator for P(X<a). We've only done unbiased estimators of parameters and some simpler functions of parameters in class.

Comment: @user164144 I edited my answer a but to help you. I am confused though that you say that you have one sample, but still talk about $\bar{X}$ in your question.

Comment: Thank you, yes. What you added helps a lot. I don't have one sample. I just asked if it was unbiased for one sample. I get what you are saying now that the indicator function is the unbiased estimator.

Answer (score 3):

Let $\theta=P(X<0)=\phi(-\mu)$ where $\phi$ is the standard normal cdf.  Assume without loss of generality that $\sigma=1$.

While dividing the number of observations $X_i<0$ by the sample size $n$ gives you an unbiased estimate of $\theta$ this estimator is likely not efficient because it throws away information.  The MLE on the other hand, $\phi(-\bar X)$, is biased for the reasons given by @Greenparker.

Consider an alternative estimator of the form
$$
\hat\theta=\phi(-a\bar X).
$$
This estimator has expected value
\begin{align}
E\hat\theta
  &=E\phi(-a\bar X) 
\\&= P(Z<-a\bar X) \quad\text{where }Z\sim N(0,1)
\\&=\phi(\frac{-a\mu}{\sqrt{1+\frac{a^2}n}}).
\end{align}
Thus, choosing $a=1/\sqrt{1-\frac1n}$, $\hat\theta$ becomes unbiased for $\theta=\phi(-\mu)$.

Based on the [Lehmann-Scheffé theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lehmann%E2%80%93Scheff%C3%A9_theorem), $\hat\theta$ is also UMVUE for $\theta$ since $\bar X$ is a sufficient statistic for $\mu$.

Comment: This seems like a much better approach than what I was thinking of but I don't understand why $E\phi(-a\bar X)=P(Z<-a\bar X)$. Can you kindly elaborate?

Comment: That follows from the definition of $\phi$ as the cdf of $Z$.

Comment: I'm sorry if I sound grossly ignorant but I've never taken an expectation of a cdf before. Frankly it's enlightening to know it can be done because as you demonstrated, this allows for determining what the bias of using $\bar x$ is.

Comment: @JarleTufto the OP seems to be interested in the case when $n=1$, and I don't think this estimator can be used in that sitaution, since the $a$ is undefined then.

Comment: @Greenparker True.  I was thinking the problem involved a random sample of size $n>1$ since the OP talks about $\bar x$.